# How to track when a certain spot on a page has been scrolled to?

Tags: jquery, analytics

I'm trying to track how many people has scrolled to a certain spot on the page.
I have managed to calculate how many clicks my navigation has but not when a user has scrolled through the page.

My HTML

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
<div class="nav">
<a href="#headingA">HEADING A</a>
<a href="#headingB">HEADING B</a>
<a href="#headingC">HEADING C</a>
</div>
</div>


<div class="headingA">Heading 1</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris luctus ultrices adipiscing. Nunc suscipit ultrices est, vel pharetra metus. Maecenas condimentum metus vitae metus rutrum vehicula. Morbi porttitor consequat tincidunt. Aliquam elementum ac nisi vel blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer dapibus egestas purus sed euismod. Vivamus vel nisl in ante venenatis porttitor. Mauris at egestas tortor.</p>
<div class="headingB">Heading 2</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris luctus ultrices adipiscing. Nunc suscipit ultrices est, vel pharetra metus. Maecenas condimentum metus vitae metus rutrum vehicula. Morbi porttitor consequat tincidunt. Aliquam elementum ac nisi vel blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer dapibus egestas purus sed euismod. Vivamus vel nisl in ante venenatis porttitor. Mauris at egestas tortor.</p>
<div class="headingC">Heading 3</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris luctus ultrices adipiscing. Nunc suscipit ultrices est, vel pharetra metus. Maecenas condimentum metus vitae metus rutrum vehicula. Morbi porttitor consequat tincidunt. Aliquam elementum ac nisi vel blandit. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Integer dapibus egestas purus sed euismod. Vivamus vel nisl in ante venenatis porttitor. Mauris at egestas tortor.</p>
```

And this is my jQuery

```
function tracker(trackVal){

if($.trim(trackVal) != ""){

}

$(document).ready(function(e) {

$(".nav a").click(function(){
    tracker($.trim($(this).html()));
    console.log($.trim($(this).html()));
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have jQuery, you can use a plugin like Waypoints (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/). It fires an event when user scrolls past a certain point on a page.

Answer (score 0):

i would probably go with a solution like this:

```
var positionOffset = $('.position-div').offset();
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= positionOffset.top){
        console.log("Position reached");
    }
});
```

Using the jquery offset function to check the element (.position-div) position on the page and the scrollTop on the window to see the scroll position.

Also maybe check to see if the window is larger than the element (.position-div). 
Simply to see if the element is visible before any scroll is handled.

EDIT:

With a check on first time scrolling:

```
var positionOffset = $('.position-div').offset();
var firstScroll = true;

$(window).scroll(function(){
   if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= positionOffset.top){
      if(firstScroll){
        firstScroll = false;
        console.log("First time scrolled to");
      } else {
          console.log("Next time scrolled to");
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: That's close to what I want but not quite. I need it to display 1 if it was scrolled for the first time and if the user scrolled back up to it then it would display 2. Does that make sense?

Comment: Check the updated answer. Just change the console.log to what ever code want to happen

Comment: That's still not it. If I'm still in the one section it keeps counting. I would like it is if I scroll down to heading A it shows 1 and then it doesn't count again if I scroll down to heading B. And when I reach heading B it shows a 1 for heading B and it doesn't count again. but if I scroll up to heading A again then it will show me a 2. Does that help?